# setting image property to a filepath

Tags: c#, .net

I have a person class as below, with an image as an attribute. I'm trying to figure out how to create an instance of the person class in my program class, and set the image of the object to a filepath, e.g. C:\Users\Documents\picture.jpg. How would I go about this?

```
 public class Person
 {
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public Image myImage { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {
    }

    public Person(string firstName, string lastName, Image image)
    {
        this.fName = firstName;
        this.lName = lastName;
        this.myImage = image;
    }
 }
```

Comment: `myImage` is of type `Image` and not `String`, so where do you want to store the file-path? Or do you want change the type of this property accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
public class Person
 {
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public Image myImage { get; set; }
    public Person()
    {
    }
    public Person(string firstName, string lastName, string imagePath)
    {
       this.fName = firstName;
       this.lName = lastName;
       this.myImage = Image.FromFile(imagePath);
    }
}
```

And instantiate like this:

```
Person p = new Person("John","Doe",@"C:\Users\Documents\picture.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your parameter-less constructor, will be as follows:

```
Person person = new Person();
Image newImage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Documents\picture.jpg");
person.myImage = newImage;
```

Although using the other constructor should be the preferred approach

Comment: Thanks, but do I need to import any namespaces in the program class to do this? I have System.Drawing, but there is no FromFile option listed after Image.

Comment: `FromFile` is part of [Image Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx). Do you have any other classes in your project that is named `Image`?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be this:

```
public Person(string firstName, string lastName, string imagePath)
{
    ...
    this.myImage = Image.FromFile(imagePath);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everyone else has already suggested `Image.FromFile`. You should be aware that this will lock the file,  which might cause problems later. More reading here:

[Why does Image.FromFile keep a file handle open sometimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788335/why-does-image-fromfile-keep-a-file-handle-open-sometimes)

Consider using the `Image.FromStream` method instead. Here's an example method that takes a path and returns an image:

```
private static Image GetImage(string path)
{
    Image image;
    using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        image = Image.FromStream(fs);
    }
    return image;
}
```

The value in this approach is that you control when you open and close your file handle.