# Deleting Image that's in PictureBox

Tags: c#, picturebox

I've searched and read a lot of the different ways to do this... and tried many of them.

When the program loads it loads printmark.png into the picture box.
Of course every time I try to delete the PNG file it says it's in use.  As you can see I've tried both the Image.FileFrom and the picturebox.Load method.

This is the code I have.

```
private void GetCurrentLogos()
    {
        Image CurrentWM = Image.FromFile(@"C:\pics\logo.png");
        Image CurrentPM = Image.FromFile(@"C:\pics\printmark.png");

        pbWatermark.Image = CurrentWM;
        pbPrintmark.Image = CurrentPM;

        //pbWatermark.Load(@"C:\pics\logo.png");
        //pbPrintmark.Load(@"C:\pics\printmark.png");
    }

    private void btnSetPM_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            ListViewItem item = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
            txtNewPM.Text = item.Tag.ToString();
            pbPrintmark.Image.Dispose();
            pbPrintmark.Image = null;
            pbPrintmark.Refresh();
            Application.DoEvents();
            renameMark("printmark.png", txtNewPM.Text);
        }
    }

    private void renameMark(string MarkType, string FileName)
    {
        string path = txtPath.Text;
        string FullSource = path + FileName;
        string FullDest = path + MarkType;

        if(File.Exists(FullDest))
        {
            File.Delete(FullDest);
        }

        System.IO.File.Copy(FullSource, FullDest);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Image.FromFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The file remains locked until the Image is disposed.

To get around this, pass the returned image to a new Bitmap so that the original lock gets released:

```
        Image tmp = Image.FromFile(@"C:\pics\logo.png");
        Image CurrentWM = new Bitmap(tmp);
        tmp.Dispose();
```

Comment: Thank you... that is probably one way I didn't try. Any reason you can think of that after I delete the file.  Then I re-run the GetCurrentLogos() function.  If I try to run the delete again it doesn't work unless I close the program and start over.  Could the IO.Copy.File be locking the file?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in some of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788335/why-does-image-fromfile-keep-a-file-handle-open-sometimes), an image created by `Image.FromFile` keeps the underlying file open.  This is by design, as the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx) says ("The file remains locked until the Image is disposed.").  You can get around this by loading the file into a `MemoryStream`, then creating the image from that stream.

Answer (score 0):

tmp.Dispose(); didnt worked for me so maybe u need also a different solution.

I used it for my dataGridView_SelectionChanged:

```
private void dataGridViewAnzeige_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var imageAsByteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    pictureBox1.Image = byteArrayToImage(imageAsByteArray);
}

public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    return returnImage;
}
```